# Unicode subscript r inconsistent

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, python-unicode

I want to use the following unicode characters in python to display the unit W_rms.

However it seems the subscript "r" is different to the others:

[image: W_rms]

I used the following codes:

```
>>> print('w\u1d63\u2098\u209b')
wᵣₘₛ
```

Any help is appreciated.

I tried to change the order of the codes, did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Just guessing because you didn't write the code in the questions (and I do not open random links from random people). `W_rms` means `W_{r}ms`, so only r is subscript. `_` apply only on next item. Write as `W_{rms}`. And learn how to better ask questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your font.  The differing characters use a fallback font when the one used doesn't support the glyph.  In Windows Notepad for example, Cambria font looks perfect, but Consolas looks like your image.  According to the Character Map utility, Consolas doesn't define the "ms" characters, but Cambria does.

Consolas: [image: Consolas font image]

Cambria: [image: Cambria font image]